# Hibernate Search Basics

Tags: hibernate, search, hibernate-search

I want to find using Hibernate Search   and  objects in same query using a MultiFieldQueryParser.

The problem is that I need to filter this entities: only not-blocked users and only finished tests should be searchable.

I tried a lot of ways...but I couldn't fin any way to put different FullTextFilter for each entity and work. :(

Do you have any idea or example about this?

Thank you!

I am using hibernate search 3.3, JPA, annotations, Spring

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use BooleanQuery instead of MultiFieldQueryParser. You can combine multiple analyzers and query types (may favorite is fuzzy) with BooleanQuery which allow you to be more precise than when you would use MultiFieldQueryParser. Take look at Lucene in Action book.